# I want to set radio button's value dynamically through database in jsp but unable

Tags: java, html, jsp

I want to set radio button's value dynamically through database in jsp but its only set the string upto space rest are ignored ex:

```
<input type="radio" name="ansrd" value=<%=request.getAttribute("optD")%>>
```

ex: `request.getAttribute("optD")` returns a string     James watt but only "James" stored in value.

Comment: How do you know that the entire string is returned?

Comment: i print this on web page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put `""` for value attribute, like this

```
<input type="radio" name="ansrd" value="<%=request.getAttribute("optD")%>" >
```

otherwise your `<input>` in generated html will end up like

```
<input type="radio" name="ansrd" value=james watt>
```

where the brower will interpret `watt` as a custom attribute